# merge is not working in the context of JPA

Tags: java, jpa

This is my simple code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("main");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        Team team1 = entityManager.find(Team.class, 0);
        System.out.println(entityManager.contains(team1));

        Team team2 = new Team();
        System.out.println(entityManager.contains(team2));

        entityManager.detach(team1);
        System.out.println(entityManager.contains(team1));

        entityManager.merge(team1);
        System.out.println(entityManager.contains(team1));

        transaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

The output is:

```
true
false
false
false
```

Look at the last `false`, it should be true because I merged that entity to the entity manager. any idea why it is giving false?

Comment: team1 = entityManager.merge(team1) will this solve your problem?

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic yes that works! thank you :) feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity manager will return new instance:

```
team1 = entityManager.merge(team1)
```

> #### 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
> propagation of state from detached
> entities onto persistent entities
> managed by the EntityManager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
> applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>   managed entity instance X' of the same
>   identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>   is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created
>   and the state of X is copied into the
>   new managed entity instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>   thrown by the merge operation (or the
>   transaction commit will fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>   however, the merge operation is
>   cascaded to entities referenced by
>   relationships from X if these
>   relationships have been annotated with
>   the cascade element value
>   `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>   annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>   cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>   `cascade=ALL`, Y is merged recursively
>   as Y'. For all such Y referenced by
>   X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note
>   that if X is managed then X is the
>   same object as X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where
>   `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>   not specified, then navigation of the
>   same association from X' yields a
>   reference to a managed object Y' with
>   the same persistent identity as Y.